# Get element of an array that corresponds to the element of another array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two arrays in numpy, `t` and `v` and suppose that `t` is strictly monotonically increasing. In my example `t` represents an array of time points and `v` the corresponding speed of a body. Now I want for example get the velocity at time `t = 3`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linear interpolation using only NumPy, you could use [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).
For example,

```
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
v = np.sin(t)
```

To find the linearly interpolated value of `v` when `t=3`:

```
In [266]: np.interp(3, t, v)
Out[266]: 0.14107783526460238
```

Note that if you wish to interpolate `v` at many values of `t`, you can pass an iterable as the first argument to `np.interp`:

```
In [292]: np.interp(np.linspace(t.min(), t.max(), 10), t, v)
Out[292]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.52741539,  0.8961922 ,  0.99540796,  0.79522006,
        0.35584199, -0.19056796, -0.67965796, -0.96431712, -0.95892427])
```

This is much more efficient than calling `np.interp` repeatedly for one value at a time.

---

To *get an element of the array*, `v`, which corresponds to `t=3` you could use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
In [272]: v[np.searchsorted(t, 3)]
Out[272]: 0.11106003812412972
```

Note, however, that `np.searchsorted` returns the index where `3` would be inserted into `t` to maintain its sortedness. So `v[np.searchsorted(t, 3)]` and `v[np.searchsorted(t, 3)+1]` sandwich the velocity at `t=3`.

Also beware that `np.searchsorted` may return an index which is 1 greater than the biggest valid index for `t` (and `v`). This happens if `3 > t.max()`:

For example, if `t` were `[1,2,3]`:

```
In [277]: np.searchsorted([1,2,3], 5)
Out[277]: 3
```

So to protect against the possible IndexError, use `np.clip` to ensure the index
is between `0` and `len(v)-1`:

```
idx = np.clip(np.searchsorted(t, 3), 0, len(v)-1)
v[idx]
```

Like `np.interp`, `np.searchsorted` can accept an iterable (here, for the second argument):

```
In [306]: v[np.clip(np.searchsorted(t, [3,4,5,6]), 0, len(v)-1)]
Out[306]: array([ 0.11106004, -0.7825875 , -0.95892427, -0.95892427])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have scipy there is a function that does precisely this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

velocity = interp1d(t, v, kind="cubic")

print(velocity(3.0))
```

See the documentation at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html